# var prototypes with a default value

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I saw a solution from Stijn de Witt for definine enums in Javascript.

```
var SIZE = {
  SMALL : {value: 0, name: "Small", code: "S"},    
  MEDIUM: {value: 1, name: "Medium", code: "M"},    
  LARGE : {value: 2, name: "Large", code: "L"}
};
```

Usage:

```
alert(SIZE.SMALL.value);
...
```

I have been trying to adapt this to allow me to define Users.

```
var RRR : {name: "RRRaney:, number: 2, date: 2007};
```

This works as I would expect:

```
alert(RRR.name + " " + RRR.date); //to display the text "RRRaney 2007".
```

I would like to try to define the .name as the default,
so I could write something like:

```
alert(RRR + " " + RRR.date);      //to display the text "RRRaney 2007".
```

or just

```
alert(RRR);                      // to display the text "RRRaney".
```

Answer (score 3):

Well this might be a bad idea and I have no idea how other browsers will handle this, but this works in chrome...

http://jsfiddle.net/yvgj8/

```
var RRR = {
             name: "RRRaney", 
             number: 2, date: 2007, 
             toString: function(){
                return this.name;
             }
          };

alert(RRR + " " + RRR.date);
```

Didn't think this would actually work, so chances are it won't in other browsers.

Comment: Checked in IE6 and IE8 and it works, very interesting.  Common practice in Java but I didn't really expect it to work in js.  Pretty useful actually.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. var USER = {RRR : {name: "RRRaney", date: 2007, toString: function() {return this.name}}};

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of would be hackish and undesirable, but here it goes:

```
var RRR = new String("RRRaney:");
RRR.date = "2007";

alert( RRR + RRR.date );
```

Instead of using a string literal for your `name`, this is borrowing a String wrapper object to be your object with a value of `"RRRaney:"`, and adding a `date` property to that wrapper object.

It gives the result you want, but seriously, don't do it. Just stick with a typical object literal.

---

You mentioned `prototype` in the title of your question.

If you were thinking of a Constructor function that gives a default `name` for the objects it creates, that's a different story:

```
var MyConstructor = function( date ) {
    this.date = date;
};

MyConstructor.prototype.name = "RRRaney:";

var inst = new MyConstructor( "2007" );
```

But it doesn't represent `RRR` in the manner you want.

Comment: dw - This was going to be my hackish attempt too, but I didn't even want to write the response.  This should not be done.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I should write this, since it is in the same spirit of kingjiv's answer. But it is slightly different, so I decided to put it here in any case.

```
function enum(name, value, date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.date = date;
}
enum.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.name;
}
```

Usage is:

```
RRR = new enum("RRRaney", 2, 2007);
alert(RRR + " " + RRR.date);
```

---

Edit: An unfortunate choice of object name. Apparently `enum` is a reserved keyword in javascript 1.3+, so the code fails in internet explorer. You need to rename it to `Enum` or some such if you want to use it.